# Audigy 2 Coaxial to Coaxial/Optical connection possible?

Tags: audio, coaxial

The original question is deleted, and asked again below with accurate information.

**Edit:**

Excuse me for my ignorance, my friend has a [Logitech Z-5500](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/speakers-audio/home-pc-speakers/devices/224) set. I thought after comparing those systems on Google images that he had the Z-680, but he hasn't.
This set has a single Digital coaxial for DVD or CD players or PC sound cards (requires coaxial cable, sold separately) cable.

This single cable was connected to the orange tulip connector (SPDIF coaxial out)
on the backside of his onboard HP Elite m9070, this connector is broken.

How can I use the digital out with a single cable coaxial cable on the Audigy2 (see image below) (I have the following converters for my disposal, can I use one of these?

- 3.5 mm male ->  coax optical
- mini optical male -> toslink optical female
- 2 x toslink optical female, toslink coupler, optical audio extension

note: Is it possible to connect a toslink cable with an mini optical male -> toslink converter on the digital out of the Audigy 2? (see image below)

[image: connectors audigy 2]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't co-axial - they all use RCA type cables. Its a little complicated though. There's RCA ports for audio (red/white) and coaxial and optical SPDIF connectors. You can convert RCA (2x 1 red and 1 white) to 3.5mm, or RCA SPDIF(1x orange, though some have white and red connectors for SPDIF out and in - but these are clearly labelled as such) SPDIF to a Optical SPDIF, but to go from SPDIF out to analogue sound (for speakers), you'll need a outboard soundcard or DAC to convert the digital signals to audio, and out to the speakers.

If your soundcard has a RCA Digital Out, that can connect to the RCA digital in of the speakers, or you'd have to go for 3x 3.5 mm connectors.